# How to get Google Analytics & Google Tag Manager to work on website embedded in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am trying to use Google Analytics GA4 and Google Tag Manager on my website.

My website is embedded in an Iframe inside another website. I see that GTM is connected when I look through the network tab but I do not see my tags firing off when expected. When I remove the website from within the Iframe my tags fire as expected. I am using the window object to push to the data layer.

Could using the window object when pushing to the data layer cause issues when the website is embedded in an Iframe? How can I have my tags fire off when my website is embedded in an Iframe?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

How I am pushing to data layer:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: "virtualPageview",
  pageName: "Page1",
  venueName: window.venueName,
  pageTitle: "Formyoula Page 1", //some arbitrary name for the page/state
});
```

Comment: Is GTM installed to the website within the iframe or is it installed to the page outside of it?

Comment: I have the same issue but when using the `gtag` method to fire events. It works in the parent frame, and even on other domains at the top-level. But once it is inside the iframe nothing is recorded in the network panel and the events are getting suppressed without a visible error message. There are no CSP's  on either domain in my use case.